# Invalid read of size 8 valgrind

Tags: c, valgrind

Im having an issue with valgrind. I have looked online for a solution(s) but have not come across anything that solves my issue. The issue experienced is an inconsistent output due to some memory issues. I've scrutinized my the code but cannot seem to find the reason for this. Im thinking the memory allocation is lost when I assign NULL values to the variables (line 288), but i'm fairly sure thats not supposed to occur.

output:

```
2015-Jun-27 12:12 PM: B's wedding
notime: (na)
```

or

```
2015-Jun-27 12:12 PM: PP?
notime: (na)
```

Code

```
typedef struct event{
char * description; 
char * time_str;
} event;

Status get_info(const CalComp *comp, FILE *const txtfile, event ** event, int * numbEvents){
int nEvents = 0;
Status status;
status.code = OK;


for(int i = 0; i < comp->ncomps; i++){
    if(strcmp(comp->comp[i]->name, "VEVENT") == 0){ //check for top level VEVENT

        *event = realloc(*event, sizeof(event)* (nEvents+1)); //line 286
        (*event)[nEvents].description = NULL;   //line 287
        (*event)[nEvents].time_str = NULL;      //line 288
        CalProp *temp = comp->comp[i]->prop;
        while(temp!=NULL){
            if(strcmp(temp->name, "DTSTART") == 0){ // Get the start time

                struct tm tm;
                char * buff = malloc(sizeof(char)*1000);
                if(strptime(temp->value, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S", &tm)==NULL){
                    perror("ERROR Converting time");
                    status.code = IOERR;
                }
                if(strftime(buff,1000, "%Y-%b-%d %l:%M %p",&tm)>0){
                    printf("time:(%s)\n", buff);
                    (*event)[nEvents].time_str = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(buff)+1);
                    strcpy((*event)[nEvents].time_str, buff);
                } else{
                    perror("ERROR Converting time");
                    status.code = IOERR;
                }
                free(buff);

            }
            if(strcmp(temp->name, "SUMMARY") == 0){ //get the summary description

                (*event)[nEvents].description = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(temp->value)+1);
                strcpy((*event)[nEvents].description, temp->value);
            }

            temp = temp->next;
        }
        if((*event)[nEvents].description== NULL){

            (*event)[nEvents].description = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
            strcpy((*event)[nEvents].description, "(na)\0");
        }
        if((*event)[nEvents].time_str == NULL){

            (*event)[nEvents].time_str= malloc(sizeof(char) * 7);
            strcpy((*event)[nEvents].time_str, "notime\0");
        }

        nEvents++;
    }

}
*numbEvents = nEvents;

for(int i = 0; i < nEvents; i++)
    printf("%s: %s\n", event[i].time_str, event[i].description);

return status;
}
```

Errors:

```
==19343== Invalid write of size 8
==19343==    at 0x100001C75: get_info (main.c:288)
==19343==    by 0x100002079: calExtract (main.c:347)
==19343==    by 0x100002283: main (main.c:387)
==19343==  Address 0x100a83a78 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==19343==    at 0x10000DEA1: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:303)
==19343==    by 0x10000ED8C: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:789)
==19343==    by 0x100001C48: get_info (main.c:286)
==19343==    by 0x100002079: calExtract (main.c:347)
==19343==    by 0x100002283: main (main.c:387)
```

Comment: "line 288" - I don't see line numbers. And unnecessary parenthetising `*event` does not make your code better readable.

Comment: @Olaf parenthesizing consistently is a good idea to prevent precedence errors

Comment: Please stop writing `\0` at the end of a string. Strings already end in `\0`.   You could simplify your code and reduce the risk of errors by using `strdup` instead of malloc-memcoy.

Comment: anyway, if you want someone to debug your code then you will need to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @M.M: That's why I wrote "unnecessary". `(*event) = ... is unnecessary **and** makes the code less clear.

Comment: @Olaf If i do not parenthesize *event,  I get errors.

Comment: @Olaf yes, I'm saying there is nothing wrong with following a consistent policy. I don't think it makes the code less clear

Comment: try `sizeof(event)` --> `sizeof(struct event)` or change variable name.

Comment: @casa235: Learn about operator preceedence and when you have to parenthetise and when not. You will not get errors for correct code.

Comment: @M.M: Coding Lisp-style in C is a bad idea.

Comment: @Olaf sorry, the earlier response was sent before I saw your reply and yes I agree.

Comment: expanding on BLUEPIXY's point, when you have `event ** event` in the prototype, then the identifier `event` inside the function body only refers to the variable name. so `sizeof(event)` is the size of a pointer (not the size of the type of the same name).  You could follow the SO-recommended malloc idiom and use `sizeof **event` instead of `sizeof(event)`  , but IMHO it is a good idea to not use the same name for a variable as for a type , to avoid this sort of problem entirely

Comment: BTW it would tidy your code up a lot for the function to do `event ev;`, then initialize `ev`, and then at the end you can do `(*event)[nEvents] = ev;` . And the 1000-byte malloc could be an automatic array instead

Comment: @BLUEPIXY it solved my issue, thanks!

Comment: And what was line 288?  ok if you've solved it either delete the question or post an answer.